# Figma layout to qtdesigner export problem

Tags: qt, qt-designer, figma

I export my layout to .qtbridge file and try to open it inside QtCreator, but doesn't work. I've read some guides on qt official website and watched videos where people just drag-and-dropped this .qtbridge file in QtDesigner. But it doesn't work for me

I tryed follow instructions on youtube and qt site

Comment: The Figma plugin isn't available with the free versions of Q Design Studio (see: [Install Qt Design Studio](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/install-qt-design-studio.html)). You would need to purchase the Enterprise Edition, or buy the Qt Bridge tools separately. Have you done that?